# How to configure a complex launchd CalendarInterval?

Tags: launchd, plist

I have a job that needs to run every hour between 09:00-15:00 M-F. How do I do that in a launchd plist file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly create a record for every hour from 9 to 15 for every day from Monday to Friday: 35 records. The cron utility has a far more compact format. With it your use case would be written as `0 9-15 * * 1-5`. [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) is a utility which creates launchd StartCalendarInterval records from cron time descriptions:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Thanks for the lead on LaunchControl! I've been using Lingon-X. I like LaunchControl more!

Comment: FWIW, here is the scripted solution for the `StartCalendarInterval` array to create the schedule: `for ((day=1;day<=5;day++)); do for ((h=9;h<=15;h++)); do echo "<dict> <key>Hour</key> <integer>$h</integer> <key>Minute</key> <integer>0</integer> <k
ey>Weekday</key> <integer>$day</integer> </dict>"; done; done`. Pasted that output to the `<array>` of the `StartCalendarInterval` array, saved, and voila